# For a CustomeObject where woud I put/find the Picklist translations?

Tags: custom-object, picklist, translation, customobjecttranslation

I have a custome object and that has a field with a picklist. Now I need to translate the picklist not via the UI I just like to know what file I need to put in which folder.

Comment: Are you talking about where to put to the translations in metadata?

Comment: A way to find out for yourself is to set the translations through the UI on a scratch org for which you have sfdx set up and simply pull the updated metadata from the org into your sfdx project (e.g. in VSCode).

Comment: I know that is what I am trying to do and I did. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to do it from the salesforce lightning setup UI, you can navigate to

```
Setup -> User Interface -> Translation Workbench -> Translate
```

here to select language, component, and do a translation.
In this screen an example of the translating `Case` `Priority` picklist value for the Swedish language:

[image]

---

If you want to update it via Metadata API, you need to work with a `objectTranslations` folder and `Case-sv.objectTransaltion` file.

You can read more about it [CustomObjectTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Normally in SFDC you can able to extract the existing translation values via [file](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.translation_file_description.htm&type=5) (.xlf **or** .stf format). You can use the same file to update/provide (if it's 1st time) the new translation values and need to upload the updated file, then the translation values are updated/applied (if new) as per uploaded file.

Below document's will be very helpful to you to do that,

Export the translate file as like this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench_export.htm&type=5)

Update/provide (if it's 1st time) the translation values and Import the updated translation file as like this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench_import.htm&type=5)

After import the file, you can receive an confirmation email from Salesforce once the translation update action is done.

Please let me know if it helps.